# Nesting selectors via loops with SASS

Tags: css, sass

I have this HTML

```
<ul> // first level
  <li>
    <ul></ul> // second level
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul> // second level
      <li>
        <ul></ul> // third level
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Is there any possible to loop nested lists one in another, to get something like this:

```
ul {
 padding: 10px;
 ul {
  padding: 20px;
  ul {
    padding: 30px;
    ... through 10 * ul
  }
 }
}
```

With this i have only list multiplication.

```
@for $i from 1 through 10 {
    ul {
        padding-left: 100 - (10 * $i) + px;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your desired CSS?  I just want to make sure what you're asking for is actually going to give you the results you think you're going to get.

Answer (score 12):

For Sass versions prior to 3.4, the function you need to do this is not part of native Sass (and recursive mixins don't work in certain versions).  You need Compass function called `nest()`.

```
$sel: '';
@for $i from 1 through 10 {
    // remove !global flag if you're using Sass < 3.3
    $sel: if($i == 1, "ul", nest($sel, "ul")) !global;

    #{$sel} {
        padding-left: 10px * $i;
    }
}
```

Sass 3.4 has a native version of this function called `selector-nest()`:

```
$sel: '';
@for $i from 1 through 10 {
    $sel: if($i == 1, "ul", selector-nest($sel, "ul")) !global;

    #{$sel} {
        padding-left: 10px * $i;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ul {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

ul ul {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

ul ul ul {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

ul ul ul ul {
  padding-left: 40px;
}

ul ul ul ul ul {
  padding-left: 50px;
}

ul ul ul ul ul ul {
  padding-left: 60px;
}

ul ul ul ul ul ul ul {
  padding-left: 70px;
}

ul ul ul ul ul ul ul ul {
  padding-left: 80px;
}

ul ul ul ul ul ul ul ul ul {
  padding-left: 90px;
}

ul ul ul ul ul ul ul ul ul ul {
  padding-left: 100px;
}
```

If you want to spell out the initial ul, then you would do it like this:

```
ul {
    // parent styles
    border: 1px solid;

    $sel: '';
    @for $i from 2 through 10 {
        $sel: if($i == 2, 'ul', nest($sel, 'ul')); // note no !global flag

        #{$sel} {
            padding-left: 10px * $i;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you *could* use simple string concatenation instead of either of these functions, but it will only work in cases where you're only nesting a single selector.  If you have 2 or more selectors, this is absolutely necessary:

```
$sel: '';
@for $i from 1 through 3 {
    $sel: if($i == 1, "article, section", selector-nest($sel, "article, section")) !global;

    #{$sel} {
      h1 {
        padding-left: 10px * $i;
      }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
article h1, section h1 {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

article article h1, article section h1, section article h1, section section h1 {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

article article article h1, article article section h1, article section article h1, article section section h1, section article article h1, section article section h1, section section article h1, section section section h1 {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

Comment: error scss/style.scss (Line 4438: Invalid CSS after "": expected selector, was "")

Comment: Seems to work to me:  http://sassmeister.com/gist/9506332.  Are you using Compass?

Comment: OK, but what if i have it in some selector like other `ul`?

Comment: All of these selectors are nested within a non-ul selector?  Or the first selector of the set of 10 is not a ul?

Comment: this nest should be in parent `ul` which i don't need loop

Comment: OK, on sassmaister it's look nice, but I still have this error `error scss/style.scss (Line 4438: Invalid CSS after "nest": expected selector, was "("ul", "ul")")` :(

Comment: Again, are you using Compass?  The `nest()` function comes from Compass, not Sass.  If you're using Compass, can you reproduce the error using Sassmeister?

Comment: If you have others ul then specify class name:  ul.otherUL { ... }

Comment: @Lukas - regarding your error  `(Line 4438: Invalid CSS after "": expected selector, was "")` - don't put the definition of the $sel variable inside a css statement but on first level.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @cimmanon's answer (which I used as a base for mine) you can simplify this and use the `&` selector to do this:

```
.listitem {
  padding: 0;
  
  $self: &;

  @for $i from 1 through 10 {
    #{$self} {
      padding-left: #{ $i * 1em };
    }
    
    $self: #{ $self + ' ' + & };
  }
}
```

This way, you can change `.listitem` to whatever you want, and you don't then need to change any selectors within the list - nothing within the loop is hard coded.

#### As a reusable mixin

Once the value for `self` becomes inherited and not hard coded, you also have the freedom to then move this all to a mixin, like so:

```
@mixin nested($depth: 5) {
  $self: &;

  @for $i from 1 through $depth {
    $nestedDepth: $i !global;
    
    #{$self} {
      @content;
    }
    
    $self: #{ $self + ' ' + & };
  }
}
```

(**sidenote:** *confusingly, compared to other languages, the `!` in CSS denotes that the following word describes the variable - e.g. `color: green !important` means that the color `green` is important. So `!global` likewise means that the SCSS variable is global - not that it is not global... Weird standard, I know, but I digress*)

The above mixin can be used as:

```
.listitem {
  padding: 0;
  
  @include nested(4) {
    padding-left: #{ $nestedDepth * 1em  };
  }
}

.otherlist {
  margin: 0;
  
  @include nested(8) {
    margin-left: #{ $nestedDepth * 1em  };
  }
}
```

And can now be re-used anywhere, with variable depths, etc