# Repeated Parent Patterns in scss

Tags: css, sass

Is there a way to simplify such structure

```
$padding: 1rem;
ul a {
  padding-left: 0 * $padding;
}

ul ul a {
  padding-left: 1 * $padding;
}
ul ul ul a {
  padding-left: 2 * $padding;
}
ul ul ul ul a {
  padding-left: 3 * $padding;
}
```

That doesn't really feel right...

the only alternative i can comeup with is one below, but it also not really plesant to eye.

```scss
ul {
  a {
    padding-left: 0 * $padding;
    ul & {
      padding-left: 1 * $padding;
      ul & {
        padding-left: 2 * $padding;
        ul & {
          padding-left: 3 * $padding;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No, that does indeed not feel right ... but not so much from the syntax point of view. What would you actually use this for? If you need the content of nested lists indented according to the nesting level, then why is that not done via a margin or padding on the `ul`?

Comment: Hey Oleg, SCSS has a built in for loop, which helps achieve this. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22349680/nesting-selectors-via-loops-with-sass) and [here](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/for/) is the official documentation for @for

Comment: Honestly, I like the first one. Even though it seems repetitive, it's easy to understand what is going on.

Comment: @ddaannnnyy hey, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple nested **[`for`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/for/)** loop would do the job for you.

Something like:

```scss
$padding: 1rem;

@for $i from 0 through 3 {
  $selector: 'ul';
  
  @for $j from 1 through $i {
    $selector: $selector + ' ul';
  }

  #{$selector} a {
    padding-left: $i * $padding;
  }
}
```

**Explanation of above code:**

- Outer `@for` loop iterates 0 through 3 times, for nested `ul` elements.
- Inner `@for` loop iterates 1 through the current iteration of the outer loop, representing the currently iterating `ul` elements.
- Finally, we can loop through the levels and build the selector string `$selector` by appending `ul` to it after which we can use the interpolation `#{}` to insert the selector string in the style rule.

**[DEMO](https://codepen.io/mandy8055/pen/XWovGJP)**

Comment: It doesn't compile to the expected CSS.